# 5.1.4: bluetooth broken?

Tags: release-hera, bluetooth

Folks; unsure how to dive into this, but I learnt that on one of my devices (HP EliteBook Folio), after upgrading to 5.1.4 Bluetooth seems "broken". State:

- No error messages in system log or dmesg.
- Bluetooth icon in panel is constantly greyed out and "disabled", enabling doesn't change that.
- Devices that have been paired don't connect anymore, new devices can't be added because the laptop can't find anything nearby.

Weird. Anyone else noticing that? Any idea how to debug or even fix this?
Thanks,
Kristian

Comment: I had some recent Bluetooth troubles too, like the mouse suddenly disconnecting and the Bluetooth icon disappearing with the computer hanging for some seconds while I was in Settings > Bluetooth to try to turn it back on. A restart did not fixed anything, but a shutdown/power on did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback... :) Well, I *think* I sort of fixed it at least temporarily in the meantime; seems the Bluetooth component in some way was (per software?) disabled via rfkill which I "fixed" - but I have no idea how that happened. It's working again, now, and I hope it will stay that way. :)